# Expansion using Pascal's triangle

Tags: binomial-theorem

I want to expand $(3k+1)^3$. When doing this I got $27k^3+9k^2+3k+1$ but when I expanded the expression by foiling I got $27k^3+9k^2+27k+1$. Which one is correct?

Comment: Neither.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: so for binomial I did.. (3k)^3+(3k)^2*1+(3k)^1*1^2+(3k)^0*1^3 is this correct?

Comment: It is $27k^3+27k^2+9k+1$.

Answer (score 1):

You have $(3k+1)^3=(3k)^3+3(3k)^2(1)+3(3k)(1)^2+1^3$, so see what this gives when you simplify.

Comment: why is it 3(3k)2(1) where did 3* the expression come from?

Comment: This came from the row 1 3 3 1 of Pascal's triangle.

Comment: so is it always 3 times the expression when to the 3rd power for the middle 2 terms?

Comment: That is right:  When you have $(a+b)^3$, the coefficients of the 4 terms are 1,3,3,1; so you get $a^3+3a^{2}b+3ab^2+b^3$.

Answer (score 1):

$$(3k+1)^3$$
The third row of Pascal's Triangle is $1,3,3,1$.  THus, these are the coefficients of each term in the expansion. Now you apply the powers in descending order for the first term, and ascending order for the second term.  THen
$$(3k+1)^3=1\cdot (3k)^3\cdot 1^0+3\cdot (3k)^2\cdot 1^1+3\cdot (3k)^1\cdot1^2+1\cdot (3k)^0\cdot1^3$$
$$=27k^3+27k^2+9k+1$$